# How to design an about me page in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, app-store, user-experience, ui-design

I am about to release a free iphone application that is targeted for all ages. My main menu contains an "About" button. How would I design my about me page? Putting it part of the main menu is the way to go? What should I include besides my name and email address?.. It would be too dull and waste of space to have a black background about me page just with my name/email address... Any suggestions from iphone app dev. veterans is appreciated

FYI- I am not releasing it on behalf of any company or organization

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mdaboutcontroller

Comment: Looks great in its simplicity! I could have "Developer" "designer" and a contact information uitableview section that includes "email" "website".. Thanks Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not have straight forward answer. As you are asking whats better to wear white t-shirt or black t-shirt. In the "About page" you are presenting yourself to the users. You should make it in a way that best represents your design style or your person. Usually simpler is better, but if you are a complex person, I would not hesitate and play with the design.

Comment: I am a beginner at graphics and designing windows/etc.. so I would like to be influenced by other people such that I can form my own style. A style which is in fact based on how I filter the suggestions based on my own taste. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would give it my name and a link to my online presence.

Comment: Alright, I could add my website/facebook page etc.. I think that would be nice.